# Problem in star delta starter in air compressor

Tags: motor, control, contactor, delta, y-to-delta

I am a beginner in electrical engineering. I am trying to understand how motors are connected in a star and delta system.

I studied the star delta starter from this [link](http://electrical-engineering-portal.com/star-delta-motor-starter). It describes the connection of a motor connection as in following diagram.

[image: star delta diagram(EEP)]

Above diagram shows V1 and V2 connected to the same phase through the main contactor and delta contactor.

But, this diagram does not match my real wiring. It seems to be wrong.

[image: Real image with connections]

What is the correct wiring scheme? Is there any problem with my connection or  with the diagram in the link. I didn't check the winding of the motor. I trusted the tag on the wire.

Comment: You trust your life to a tag generated by someone else.  Check the windings.  Especially for that rats nest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Above diagram shows V1 and V2 connected to same phase through the main contactor and delta contactor. 
>   But,This diagram is wrong according to my real connection.

You are correct. The diagram is wrong.

[image]

*Figure 1. Here is the same crude drawing but the phase sequence is correct and somebody has coloured it up. Source: [Electrical Notes](https://electricalnotes.wordpress.com/2012/03/16/star-delta-starter/).*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Abkh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Drawing of your wiring looks OK.*

> I didn't check the winding of the motor. I trusted the tag on the wire.

Very foolish.

The panel wiring in your photo is atrocious. It needs a major tidy up.